# Move tokens for node one by one or simultaneously?

Tags: cassandra

When adding new node should I really perform **nodetool move [token]** one by one? Is it a good practice to move tokens for more than one nodes simultaneously? For example, could I process multiple nodes from arbitary not related replica sets in that way?

Datastax docs says "No". I think I can, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

When you move the token, you should also move the data associated with that token. That could be a lot of data. That data has to travel over your network.  There is the danger of saturating your network links if yiu move much data simultaneously.  So you can do it. But perhaps you ought nit to.

Answer (score 0):

A [rather old Datastax documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/operations/cluster_management#adding-nodes-to-a-cluster) says

> [...] and then run nodetool move , one node at a time.